# dnsmasq not responding DHCP requests that don't follow a DHCP discover

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server, dnsmasq

I have an instance of `dnsmasq` running on network namespace X, and I run `dhclient` (or any other dhcp client) from within network namespace Y to obtain an IP address on a given interface. The two network namespaces are on the same `openvswitch` bridge, through which they communicate.

I see that `dnsmasq` takes ages to reply, somewhere between 10 and 30 seconds, even if a `tcpdump` shows that all DHCP packets are promptly delivered to the destination namespace.

Why does it take so long? Is there a way to reduce this delay?

Here's an example from /var/log/syslog where the IP address is assigned after 11 seconds:

```
Apr  4 14:31:27 localhost dhclient: Listening on LPF/_0.ping/ae:ca:22:bc:3c:7b
Apr  4 14:31:27 localhost dhclient: Sending on   LPF/_0.ping/ae:ca:22:bc:3c:7b
Apr  4 14:31:27 localhost dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Apr  4 14:31:27 localhost dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on _0.ping to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Apr  4 14:31:33 localhost dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on _0.ping to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Apr  4 14:31:48 localhost dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on _0.ping to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
Apr  4 14:31:48 localhost dnsmasq-dhcp[11719]: DHCPDISCOVER(_0.dhcp) 192.168.31.110 ae:ca:22:bc:3c:7b 
Apr  4 14:31:48 localhost dnsmasq-dhcp[11719]: DHCPOFFER(_0.dhcp) 192.168.31.110 ae:ca:22:bc:3c:7b 
Apr  4 14:31:48 localhost dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on _0.ping to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Apr  4 14:31:48 localhost dhclient: DHCPOFFER from 192.168.31.1
Apr  4 14:31:48 localhost dnsmasq-dhcp[11719]: DHCPREQUEST(_0.dhcp) 192.168.31.110 ae:ca:22:bc:3c:7b 
Apr  4 14:31:48 localhost dnsmasq-dhcp[11719]: DHCPACK(_0.dhcp) 192.168.31.110 ae:ca:22:bc:3c:7b mymachine
Apr  4 14:31:48 localhost dnsmasq-dhcp[11719]: not giving name mymachine to the DHCP lease of 192.168.31.110 because the name exists in /etc/hosts with address 127.0.0.1
Apr  4 14:31:48 localhost dhclient: DHCPACK from 192.168.31.1
Apr  4 14:31:48 localhost dhclient: ntp-servers: expecting at least 4 bytes; got 0
Apr  4 14:31:48 localhost dhclient: bound to 192.168.31.110 -- renewal in 33935 seconds.
```

The `dnsmasq` instance is launched with the following command:

```
dnsmasq --dhcp-range=set:tag0,192.168.31.100,192.168.31.150,24h -l /tmp/dnsmasq-leasefile.dhcp.dhcp --dhcp-option=tag:tag0,option:router,192.168.31.2 --dhcp-option=tag:tag0,option:dns-server,9.9.9.9 --dhcp-option=tag:tag0,42
```

**EDIT**
Ok, I ran it a few more times and I think I see a pattern in there. The DHCP client starts by sending two DHCP requests, which are both unanswered. As soon as a DHCP discover is sent, `dnsmasq` replies. The reason why `dhclient` first tries with a DHCP request is that it sees a previous lease for the same interface in `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases` and tries requesting the IP address appearing there. As soon as I remove such file, the response from `dnsmasq` is generated instantly. I see two options:

- I tell `dhclient` not use its lease file (not sure how), but this is not really ideal...
- I instruct `dnsmasq` to respond to requests that don't follow a discover message. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is to use `--dhcp-authoritative` option in dnsmasq. The problem was that I was restarting the dnsmasq server each time, so it had no lease file, but dhclient had its own lease file. Not being able to verify requested IP address in its own lease file, dnsmasq waits until a dhcp discover message is issued.

Comment: There must be additional explanations because I run dnsmasq and I constantly see dnsmasq ignoring dhcp REQUEST packets. In the dnsmasq log it says it sends an ACK but the ACK is not observable on the interface with tcpdump. The hosts being ignored are in the leases file.